# SQL stuff and coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello I just want to know something..
Say I have this following query..

```
DECLARE @earninglist varchar(1000)
       Set @earninglist=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],['
            +LTRIM([Description]) FROM
            PR_Earnings 
            ORDER BY '],[' + LTRIM([Description])
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '')+']'

Declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='Select '+@earninglist+' from earnings;'
exec(@sql);
```

say that earning list contains this fields: 'Cola','Incentives'
How can I declare @earninglist so that I can get this following query:

```
set @sql='Select Coalesce([Cola],0)Cola,Coalesce([Incentives],0)Incentives from earnings'
```

using stuff.. please help..

hmm.. if you notice that @earninglist in the first set @sql .. it will turn out to be like this: `'Select [Cola],[Incentives] from earnings'` what i want to do is to make the result set of @earninglist to be like this:`'Select Coalesce([Cola],0)Cola,Coalesce([Incentives],0)Incentives from earnings'` .. is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as:

```
DECLARE @earninglist varchar(1000)
       Set @earninglist=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],Coalesce([' +LTRIM([Description])+'],0)['+LTRIM([Description]) FROM
            PR_Earnings 
            ORDER BY '],Coalesce([' +LTRIM([Description])+'],0)['+LTRIM([Description])
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '')+']'

Declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='Select '+@earninglist+' from earnings;'
exec (@sql);
```